# Connection to sqlite database is not working

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to store the value of an input field in a database (player.db) when a button is clicked. Unfortunately, the whole thing doesn't work yet and despite hours of research I can't find the error. The database and my javascript are in the same folder. Here is my JS code:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

document.getElementById('neuerSpieler').addEventListener('click', function() {
  
  let db = new sqlite3.Database('player.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Verbunden mit der Datenbank.');
  });

  
  let inputValue = document.getElementById('inputField').value;
    
  if (inputValue) {
    let id = 1;
    let sql = `INSERT INTO Spieler (id, spielernamen) VALUES (?, ?)`;
    db.run(sql, inputValue, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
      console.log(`Ein neuer Datensatz wurde hinzugefügt.`);
    });
  }

  db.close((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Verbindung zur Datenbank wurde geschlossen.');
  });
});
```

I can change my database player.db via the command line without any problems.
My database so far consists of nothing but this:

```
CREATE TABLE "players" ( "id" INTEGER, "name" TEXT, PRIMARY KEY("id") )
```

It would mean the world to me if someone could help me here!

Comment: When you're posting question, it helps to indicates what is the output or the symptoms/behaviour of your program and what you would expect instead. Just stating "it doesn't work" doesn't provide much information so we are just guessing what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'll try to be a little more detailed. Basically I'm trying to set up a local database for a mobile app that accepts a maximum of 6 player names. First of all, I wanted to test how I can feed information into my database. Unfortunately I can't do that. So far I can only say that there is no error with the path or the IDs. It seems that the connection to the database is not even established. Actually, I followed tutorials strictly. The database itself doesn't seem to be faulty as I can easily modify the database from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to be here:

```
let id = 1;
    let sql = `INSERT INTO Spieler (id, spielernamen) VALUES (?, ?)`;
    db.run(sql, inputValue, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
      console.log(`Ein neuer Datensatz wurde hinzugefügt.`);
    });
```

The SQL statement is requiring 2 parameters but is seems only one value is given there.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still not working. I will try further. I changed the line like this: db.run(sql, [1, inputValue], function(err) {